# How to take square root of large numbers in Python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to check if a large number is a perfect square. Here is the corresponding part of my code:

```
x = long(raw_input())
a = sqrt(5 * x ** 2 + 4)
b = sqrt(5 * x **2 - 4)
if long(a) == a or long(b) == b:
    print "YES"
else:
    print "NO"
```

However, when x becomes too large, I get this error:

```
    a = sqrt(5 * x ** 2 + 4)
OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float
```

Can anybody tell me a workaround for this?

Comment: You could try [Newton's method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850100/finding-the-square-root-using-newtons-method-errors).

Comment: There are better ways for determining if a number is a perfect square (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer), for example).

Comment: @erip you mean python can’t do this ?

Comment: You're using the wrong algorithm. Try to find something that doesn't rely on big numbers.

Comment: @xrisk if you looked at the link, it was implemented in Python. In any case, I think arshajii's solution is smarter.

Comment: You could use higher precision numbers. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663272/double-precision-floating-values-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [decimal module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) to take the square root of large numbers.